# Typo3: How can i set common data in header and footer like logo?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, headerfooter

I want to set a dynamic logo for mobile and desktop versions in header footer.
I want to set an email, phone number and address in the footer. how can I set all data in one place?
Should I store every page of all data?

Comment: You can use constant editor for this

Comment: is this extension? can you give me a referral link? I am new in typo3.

Comment: Check my answer, I have given example for creating constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constant is basically for a general setting, you can create in your base template. However, sitepackagebuilder provides minimal setting.

It's pretty easy! You can create your own constant with simple code below:

1. Create constant, Add constant in your constant.ts (Generally file path is ext/yourExt/Configuration/TypoScript)

   ```
   plugin.tx_yourplugin {
      settings {
          # cat=plugin.tx_yourplugin/file; type=string; label=Website Logo
          siteLogo =
      }
   }
   ```

Now, you will find constant in your TYPO3 backend template->constant Editor module, within your extension constants.

2. Assign a value to setup.ts: Add below code in your setup.ts which is located in the same directory.

   ```
   plugin.tx_yourplugin {
       settings {
          siteLogo = {$plugin.tx_yourplugin.settings.siteLogo}
       }
   }
   ```

Now, your dynamic value from constant can be accessible to your fluid template or your extbase controller. You will find your constant in the settings user below debug.

```
<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>
```

Here is some useful link:

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/UsingSetting/Constants.html
- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/UsingSetting/TheConstantEditor.html#type

As far as I know, a multiline constant and type `file` is not yet supported.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hello GNB, Thanks for your answer. It's really helpful. So here we could not have file type or textarea? We have to set the URL of the logo OR We can uploaded file from Constant?

Comment: multiline constant and type file is not yet supported yet, I am really not sure but yeah. may be you can create your own type for constant. Check out the second link

Comment: <f:debug>{_all}</f:debug> code was not returning siteLogo variable in "/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/Default.html".

Answer (score 1):

Check out Bootstrap Package (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/bootstrap_package/), a popular, ready-to-use TYPO3 extension that provides a responsive theme for TYPO3. With it, you can easily customize the header and footer across all pages. As the extension's name implies, it makes extensive use of the Bootstrap framework.

Comment: I am using my own sitepackagebuilder package. In that how can we use the bootstrap package?

Comment: OK great. When you kickstart a TYPO3 extension using https://sitepackagebuilder.com, you can choose which base package you want: Bootstrap Package or Fluid Styled Content (FSC). If you choose the Bootstrap Package version, you'll have a lot more features out of the box. This includes several backend layouts (also used in the frontend), and a responsive navbar with logo and navigation. The FSC version is for people who want to develop their own theme from the ground up. Since you are new to TYPO3 you may want to switch. Let me know and I will update my answer with some details.

Comment: Thank you phvt for precious time. I am using Fluid Styled Content (FSC) because I have HTML design. Can you please suggest what I need to do in FSC package.